# Packing a struct with a union of structs within it

Tags: c, struct, alignment, unions

I'm having an issue with structure packing in C.  I want the size of this structure to be 4 bytes with all fields in this order, but it ends up being padded out to 8 bytes.  I'm guessing that the problem is happening because `dclInput` and `dclOutput` are being aligned to a 4-byte boundary.  Is it possible to tell the compiler to not align those structures and just trust that I am not going to ask for a pointer to either one?  I have tried using `#pragma pack(1)` but that didn't help.  EDIT: Unfortunately, `__attribute__((packed))` doesn't work either - the size still ends up being 8 bytes.

```
struct _IL_OPCODE {
    unsigned code : 16;
    union {
        struct {
            unsigned usage    : 5;
            unsigned mode     : 3;
            unsigned          : 1;
            unsigned bias     : 1;
            unsigned invert   : 1;
            unsigned centered : 1;
            unsigned          : 4;
        } dclInput;
        struct {
            unsigned id          : 8;
            unsigned type        : 4;
            unsigned             : 3;
            unsigned unnormalize : 1;
        } dclResource;
    };
};
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? For GCC it should be `__attribute__ ((__packed__))`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with some compilers, but is not portable C, so you should probably not rely on it.

For example, in gcc, you can use the `packed` type attribute:

```
struct _IL_OPCODE {
    unsigned code : 16;
    union {
        struct {
  ...
    } __attribute__ ((packed))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the `#pragma pack(1)` *before* your structure or union?

```
#pragma pack(1)          // Put it here OR
struct _IL_OPCODE {
  unsigned code : 16;
  #pragma pack(1)        // here
  union {
    struct {
      unsigned usage    : 5;
      unsigned mode     : 3;
      unsigned          : 1;
      unsigned bias     : 1;
      unsigned invert   : 1;
      unsigned centered : 1;
      unsigned          : 4;
    } dclInput;
    struct {
      unsigned id          : 8;
      unsigned type        : 4;
      unsigned             : 3;
      unsigned unnormalize : 1;
    } dclResource;
  };
};
```

I can get the size down to four bytes with this. `__attribute__ ((packed))` gave me six bytes.

Comment: `#pragma pack(1)` is the Visual C way to do this, `__attribute__((packed))` is the gcc way.  Both compilers will ignore the "other" way, I believe.   Other compilers my do differently.   Hence the "not portable".

Comment: I don't know about Visual C ignoring the 'gcc' way, but gcc does support `#pragma pack`. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html for info.